# Bootstrap Column not working as Expected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-options

I am having a bootstrap div with 3 columns as given in the html below and when i have a select control in the first div of the row, the remaining div's don't show up. but if i comment out the same and check with hello world text. All columns show up just like it should be.

not sure what is that i am missing, hence looking out for a new set of eyes to point out what is wrong. :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Wind Monitoring System </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
      <span>Hello World1</span>
      <!--<div>
                    <select id="states" ng-model="selectedState" ng-change="getCities()" size="3" ng-options="state.Name for state in states" />
                </div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
      <span>Hello World2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
      <span>Hello World3</span>
      <!--<select id="city" ng-show="selectedState != null" ng-model="selectedCity" size="3" style="height:200px;width:200px" ng-options="city.city for city in cities | filter : {State:selectedState.Name}" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the select tags should be as such `<select></select>` I believe you are supposed to be binding your options not your `<select>` tags.

[Check this link out](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Okay here you go

**HTML**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Wind Monitoring System </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
        <span>Hello World1</span>
        <div ng-controller="Test">
            <select ng-model="selectedState" size="3" ng-options="item for item in items"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
      <span>Hello World2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue">
      <span>Hello World3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Test',function($scope){
   $scope.items = ['one','two','three','four']
});
```

I believe all I did was add the closing  tag.

Comment: i am using angularjs to create the options, thus the html provided is correct.

Comment: I'm looking at AngularJS documentation and the one that is looping is the options not the select tags, check it out here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are talking about give me a moment, I'll see what I can do.